# Is there any thing in judaism that says cook your food well at high temprature

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilla, minhag, kashrut-kosher

Is there any thing in judaism that says cook your food well at high temprature

Comment: Ushmartem es nafshoseichem - gurad your *health*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some foods yes,like beets. See Eruvin 29:

אָמַר רַב חִסְדָּא: תַּבְשִׁיל שֶׁל תְּרָדִין יָפֶה לַלֵּב וְטוֹב לָעֵינַיִם, וְכׇל שֶׁכֵּן לִבְנֵי מֵעַיִים. אָמַר אַבָּיֵי: וְהוּא דְּיָתֵיב אַבֵּי תָפֵי וְעָבֵיד תּוֹךְ תּוֹךְ.

Rav Chisda said:a dish of Beets are good for the heart ,eyes and intestines . Abaye said this applies when the beets are sitting on the stove and the cooking noise "tuch,tuch" is heard.

The gemara before this explain that partially cooked beets are dangerous to it.